# I want to build regex, which gives me back specific string

Tags: regex, c#-4.0

I have an array of strings. Now I have to build a regex, which gives me a string, which starts with a single letter, then \ , then 4 digits.

I tried the following code.

```cs
namespace ConsoleApplication 
{
    class Program 
    {
        static void Main(string[] args) 
        {
            string[] testStrings = new string[] { "w:\WES\1234", "w:\WES\4567", "w:\WES\856432", "w:\WES\AdK1234qw", "w:\WES\abcdesf};
            string RegEx = Regex.Escape("\b\d+\w*\b");

            foreach(var testString in testStrings) 
            {
                string f = Regex.Escape(testString );                   
                Match match = Regex.Match(f, @RegEx);             

                // Here we check the Match instance.
                if (!match.Success)
                {                 
                    continue;                      
                }
                console.writeline("teststringcorrect", match.value);
            }
```

I expect an answer back.
"w:\WES\1234" and "w:\WES\4567"

How can I change my regex pattern to find the right string for me?

**Edit** My code after adjustments suggested by Andrew Morton:

```
string root = @"C:emp\WES";  // Outputdebug: C:emp\WES
Regex re= new Regex("^" + Regex.Escape(root) + @"\\[0-9]{4}$");   // outputdebug: re.Pattern : ^C:emp\\WES\\[0-9]{4}$           
string[] subfolder = Directory.GetDirectories(root); // ouputdebug: {string[4]}. [0]:C:emp\WES\1234 [1]:C:emp\WES\5678 [3]:C:emp\WES\wqder [4]:C:emp\WES\60435632
var dirs = Directory.EnumerateDirectories(root).Where(d => re.IsMatch(d)); // outputdebug: {system.link.Enumerable.WhereEnumarableIteraTOR<STRING>} Current is Null
foreach (var folder in subfolder)
{
    string f = Regex.Escape(folder);
    Match match = re.Match(f);   // outputdebug: groups is 0           
                                    // Here we check the Match instance.
    if (!match.Success)
    {
        continue;
    }
}
```

Comment: string always begins with w:\WES, then \ then digit with 4 digits.  how can i make regex-pattern?? Thanks you

Comment: In your requirement you've said that you're trying to match a single letter followed by \ then 4 digits. But in your examples what you're trying to match is a single letter followed by :\, followed by three letters and a \ then 4 numbers. Can you please clarify your requirements?
And what if anything is your current regex matching?

Comment: i am trying to match  a string(which is fixed) "w:\WES " followed by  \ then 4 numbers.

Comment: my current regex(match) is empty.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must not escape the string you are inspecting (`testString`) because that can change it.

You can use the `@` symbol to make the following string a literal (e.g. `@"\r"` would be seen as a backslash and an r, instead of a carriage return character). Even with that, literal backslashes in a regex need to be escaped as `\\`.

To output more than one string with Console.WriteLine(), you have to concatenate them with `+`.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    string[] testStrings = new string[] { @"w:\WES\1234", @"w:\WES\4567", @"w:\WES\856432", @"w:\WES\AdK1234qw", @"w:\WES\abcdesf"};
    Regex re =new Regex(@"^w:\\WES\\[0-9]{4}$");

    foreach (var testString in testStrings)
    {
        Match match = re.Match(testString);

        if (match.Success)
        {
                 Console.WriteLine("teststringcorrect " + match.Value);

        }
    }

    Console.ReadLine();

}
```

Outputs:

```
teststringcorrect w:\WES\1234
teststringcorrect w:\WES\4567
```

---

Based on that, if you had a directory and you wanted to find subdirectories of it which had names of exactly four digits, you could do something like:

```
string root = @"C:\temp";
Regex re = new Regex("^" + Regex.Escape(root) + @"\\[0-9]{4}$");
var dirs = Directory.EnumerateDirectories(root).Where(d => re.IsMatch(d));

Console.WriteLine(string.Join("\r\n", dirs));
```

which might output

```
C:\temp\4321
C:\temp\9876
```